# Rotating JPEG Images using TSQL, is it possible?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, rotation, jpeg

A customer has a SQL Server 2008 R2 database where nearly all images were stored upside down. It is neither possible to patch the software nor write an external script using a SQL Server library to access until one to two weeks.

The only possibility we have now to modify records in the database is executing TSQL scripts. So my question is: Is there any way of rotating JPEG images with TSQL?

I could not think of one really myself (honestly I also do not believe there is, but I thought I ask here first) or found something in the docs.

Comment: I'm sure it's possible, but I'm not sure it's sensible

Answer (score 2):

looks like you have to create a CLR function which is capable of doing this. Generally, this is something that should not made within SQL server.
If this is a one-time operation, why don't you create a small project which is getting all images from the DB, rotate it and store it again?

Comment: The instance is running on a machine were our team only has TSQL access. The process of granting us the privileges to execute even a small python script or .NET app would take too long. Same for deploying a CLR function.

Comment: What do you mean by "TSQL Access" ?

Comment: Having "tsql access" is enough to query all necessary data into c#-client, manipulate it, then write it back ;)

Comment: I mean we only have an SQL user who has SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT ... rights on the tables in the target database.

Comment: @xacinay the database is only accessible within a network were we have no machine to deploy code on it

Comment: Then, the most reasonable approach in my opinion would be using 'xp..cmdshell' for downloading and manipulating files. [Here is](http://www.nigelrivett.net/FTP/s_ftp_GetFile.html) the example.  If your permissions are cut to DML operations only, it wont work unfortunately.